# Why isn't server side Javascript popular?

Tags: javascript, web-deployment

Does anyone have a general idea why server side Javascript hasn't been as popular as using a multi-language approach to web development? I.E. JavaScript+C#, JavaScript+perl; why not just Javascript all around? Wouldn't specific cost associated with web dev diminish if everyone's using a single language?

Comment: Look here : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451143/why-server-side-javascript-is-not-widely-used)

Comment: Java JDK has Rhino built into it.  That's not the impediment.

Comment: I've heard they're kinda slow compared to established server languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's not the most used language for the server-side, Javascript is since a few years kind of popular on the server.

You should look at [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js), for example.

It used to be considered just a toy language to show pop-ups with ads, but nowadays people is realizing it's power.

You can read an essay about this called [JavaScript:
The World's Most Misunderstood Programming Language](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/javascript.html) to get a point of view about the reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Having never used server side javascript myself, I can honestly say it hasn't been around for very long compared to PHP, Python, Ruby, Java and so on, plus the advantages are not yet been publicized widely.

Having read something about it, it sounds really interesting, i think with a bit more time MVC javascript frontend coupled with server side will become a more widely adopted solution.

Another reason that comes into my mind is that some people really love language X or Y.

Me for example, I love python/django and i don't dislike ruby/rails.

Answer (score -3):

Javascript is browser manipulation. You use server-side languages to populate a page, then use client-side languages to make it pretty.

Comment: Surely it is possible to use javascript on server side as well.

Comment: [tag:node.js] works server-side; and this answer is, at best, a comment since it doesn't begin to touch on use-cases or in any way address the 'why' of the question asked.